# Using PHP to load entered form option

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am trying to make it so when the filtered options are entered when the page reloads it has the previously entered options. Image:

[image]
Here is the current code: (Sorry it is messy, currently just learning web development)

Body: http://hastebin.com/ofiqucayuf.bash The format messed up in here so I think it must be some syntax error.

The last change now makes it so it goes to Sold rather than For Sale

Comment: are u using `1 OR Sold = 0` in your query?

Comment: Only if All Paintings is selected.

Comment: `{; echo " selected"; };` can u plz check the starting semi colon here?

Comment: Fixed that, however still not solved the problem.

Comment: Then, you have to paste whole code. From here, it looks fine.

Comment: Okay, added to the question

Comment: `" selected"` remove extra space and use `echo "selected=''";`

Comment: your code is open for SQL injection, this `1 OR Sold = 0` will hurt u badly

Comment: I presumed it would be, I will have to look into preventing that after.

Comment: Updated: http://hastebin.com/ofiqucayuf.bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose `O` & `1` in single quotes. It will work.

***Modified Code***

```
<select class="form-control" name="status">
    <option value='1 OR Sold = 0'
    <?php if ($_POST["status"] == "1 OR Sold = 0") { 
    echo "selected"; }; ?>>All Paintings</option>";
    <option value='0' <?php if ($_POST["status"] == '0') {echo "selected"; }; ?>>For Sale</option>
    <option value='1' <?php if ($_POST["status"] == '1') { echo "selected"; }; ?>>Sold</option>
</select>
```